# eBay API findItemsAdvanced call returns 'Value is required for item filter, CONDITION

Tags: ebay-api

I'm playing a little bit around with the API of eBay and trying to get a list of books that are everything but new and which have the keyword "tolkien". Somehow I'm not getting a list, but I'm getting an error.

This is the url I'm trying:

```
https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1
?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced
&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0
&SECURITY-APPNAME=XXXXXXXXX
&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON
&REST-PAYLOAD=true
&keywords=tolkien
&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-DE
&itemFilter(0).name=ListingType
&itemFilter(0).value=FixedPrice
&categoryId=267
&itemFilter(1).name=Condition
&itemFilter(1).value(0)=2000
&itemFilter(1).value(1)=2500
&itemFilter(1).value(2)=3000
&itemFilter(1).value(3)=4000
&itemFilter(1).value(4)=5000
&itemFilter(1).value(5)=6000
```

And this is what I get back:

```
{
    "findItemsAdvancedResponse": [
        {
            "ack": [
                "Failure"
            ],
            "errorMessage": [
                {
                    "error": [
                        {
                            "errorId": [
                                "46"
                            ],
                            "domain": [
                                "Marketplace"
                            ],
                            "severity": [
                                "Error"
                            ],
                            "category": [
                                "Request"
                            ],
                            "message": [
                                "Value is required for item filter, CONDITION."
                            ],
                            "subdomain": [
                                "Search"
                            ],
                            "parameter": [
                                "CONDITION"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "version": [
                "1.13.0"
            ],
            "timestamp": [
                "2019-07-03T22:12:21.645Z"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you show the result without any filter?

Comment: The result without any filter, is a huge json file. So I pasted it on code pile. https://www.codepile.net/pile/wp4WP51n

Comment: &keywords=tolkien and you put in the comments talkien

Comment: I'm searching for books of Tolkien of course .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it, by moving the category filter before the other filter.

```
https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1
?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced
&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0
&SECURITY-APPNAME=XXXXXXXXX
&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON
&REST-PAYLOAD=true
&keywords=tolkien
&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-DE
&categoryId=267
&itemFilter(0).name=ListingType
&itemFilter(0).value=FixedPrice
&itemFilter(1).name=Condition
&itemFilter(1).value(0)=2000
&itemFilter(1).value(1)=2500
&itemFilter(1).value(2)=3000
&itemFilter(1).value(3)=4000
&itemFilter(1).value(4)=5000
&itemFilter(1).value(5)=6000
```